# can a user interact with WKInterfacePicker with touch gestures?

Tags: watchos-2

is it possible to interact with WKInterfacePicker object also with the fingers, not only with the digital crown?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot interact that way, the only way to interact with WKInterfacePicker is via digital crown.
As mentioned in the link http://www.toptal.com/ios/apple-watch-in-a-nutshell

**User interaction (or wearer interaction, if preferred) can occur in 4 different ways:**

- simple touch: a tap on a button is a typical example
- force touch: activated by applying more force when tapping and holding the screen. Similar to the right mouse click on a PC it will display a contextual menu (containing up to 4 items)
- gesture: vertical swipe to scroll, horizontal swipe to navigate between pages, left edge swipe to navigate back
- digital crown: hardware input used for fine tuned scrolling